# I am using p5.js and ml5.js. How do I set the background of a canvas to the camera?

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, p5.js, ml5.js

I'm using [posenet (via ml5)](https://learn.ml5js.org/#/reference/posenet). I have created an app that draws a picture of a person detected through the camera onto a canvas (a 2D avatar). Currently the `video` camera and p5 sketch use seprate canvas elements. I want to figure out how to set the background of the p5.js canvas to be the `video` camera camera.

Maybe I should use the `background();` function ?

I tried using the `VIDEO` and `Video` as arguments to
`background();` but it didn't work.

can someone please help?

This is my sketch code (assumes you have p5.js and ml5.js added in the HTML):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.4.3/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
```

```js
let nosex, nosey, learx, leary, rearx, reary, leyex, leyey, reyex, reyey, lhipx, lhipy, rhipx, rhipy, lsholx, lsholy, rsholx, rsholy, lelbx, lelby, relbx, relby, lwrix, lwriy, rwrix, rwriy, lankx, lanky, rankx, ranky, lknex, lkney, rknex, rkney, angel;

    function setup() {
      video = createCapture(VIDEO);
      video.size(550, 500);
      canvas = createCanvas(550, 550);
      canvas.position(560, 150);
      poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelLoaded);
      poseNet.on('pose', gotPoses);
      angleMode(DEGREES);
    }

    function draw() {
      background("#ffffff");
      fill('#ebca7f');
      stroke('#ebca7f');
      quad(nosex - ((learx + rearx) / 2) + rearx, nosey - 20, nosex + ((learx - rearx) / 2), nosey - 20, ((lsholx - rsholx) * 0.60) + rsholx, lsholy - 30, ((lsholx - rsholx) * 0.40) + rsholx, rsholy - 30);
      strokeWeight(20);
      fill(color);
      stroke('#000000');
      quad(lhipx, lhipy, rhipx, rhipy, rsholx, rsholy - 30, lsholx, lsholy - 30);
      line(lsholx, lsholy, lelbx, lelby);
      line(lelbx, lelby, lwrix, lwriy);
      line(rsholx, rsholy, relbx, relby);
      line(relbx, relby, rwrix, rwriy);
      stroke('#000000');
      line(lhipx, lhipy, lknex, lkney);
      line(lknex, lkney, lankx, lanky);
      line(rhipx, rhipy, rknex, rkney);
      line(rknex, rkney, rankx, ranky);
      angel = leary - reary;
      translate(nosex, nosey);
      rotate(angel / 2.5);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      strokeWeight(0);
      fill('#ffda82');
      stroke('#ffda82');
      ellipse(0, 0, rearx - learx * 1.1, rearx - learx * 1.1);
      translate(-nosex, -nosey);
      fill('#000000');
      stroke('#000000');
      rect(leyex, leyey, (rearx - learx) / 10, (rearx - learx) / 10);
      fill('#000000');
      stroke('#000000');
      rect(reyex, reyey, (rearx - learx) / 10, (rearx - learx) / 10);
      fill('#c7a75b');
      stroke('#c7a75b');
      rect(nosex, nosey, (rearx - learx) / 8, (rearx - learx) / 8);
      fill('#f0c3a5');
      stroke('#f0c3a5');
      rect(nosex, nosey + (rearx - learx * 1.1) * -0.194, (rearx - learx) / 1.5, (rearx - learx) / 10);
      fill('#734603');
      stroke('#734603');
      rect(nosex, nosey - (rearx - learx * 1.1) * -0.44444, (rearx - learx), (rearx - learx) * -0.2);
    }

    function modelLoaded() {
      console.log('PoseNet is Initialized');
    }

    function gotPoses(results) {
      if (results.length > 0) {
        leary = results[0].pose.leftEar.y;
        learx = results[0].pose.leftEar.x;
        reary = results[0].pose.rightEar.y;
        rearx = results[0].pose.rightEar.x;
        leyey = results[0].pose.leftEye.y;
        leyex = results[0].pose.leftEye.x;
        reyey = results[0].pose.rightEye.y;
        reyex = results[0].pose.rightEye.x;
        nosey = results[0].pose.nose.y;
        nosex = results[0].pose.nose.x;
        lhipx = results[0].pose.leftHip.x;
        lhipy = results[0].pose.leftHip.y;
        rhipx = results[0].pose.rightHip.x;
        rhipy = results[0].pose.rightHip.y;
        lsholx = results[0].pose.leftShoulder.x;
        lsholy = results[0].pose.leftShoulder.y;
        rsholx = results[0].pose.rightShoulder.x;
        rsholy = results[0].pose.rightShoulder.y;
        lelbx = results[0].pose.leftElbow.x;
        lelby = results[0].pose.leftElbow.y;
        relbx = results[0].pose.rightElbow.x;
        relby = results[0].pose.rightElbow.y;
        lwrix = results[0].pose.leftWrist.x;
        lwriy = results[0].pose.leftWrist.y;
        rwrix = results[0].pose.rightWrist.x;
        rwriy = results[0].pose.rightWrist.y;
        lknex = results[0].pose.leftKnee.x;
        lkney = results[0].pose.leftKnee.y;
        rknex = results[0].pose.rightKnee.x;
        rkney = results[0].pose.rightKnee.y;
        lankx = results[0].pose.leftAnkle.x;
        lanky = results[0].pose.leftAnkle.y;
        rankx = results[0].pose.rightAnkle.x;
        ranky = results[0].pose.rightAnkle.y;
      }
    }

    function generateRainbowHex() {
      time = new Date().getTime();
      frequency = 0.001;
      amplitude = 127;
      red = Math.sin(frequency * time + 0) * amplitude + 128;
      green = Math.sin(frequency * time + 2 * Math.PI / 3) * amplitude + 128;
      blue = Math.sin(frequency * time + 4 * Math.PI / 3) * amplitude + 128;
      hexCode = `#${Math.round(red).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')}${Math.round(green).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')}${Math.round(blue).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')}`;
      return hexCode;
    }
    setInterval(() => {
      color = generateRainbowHex();
    }, 1);
```

Comment: Please share your code in the question itself. You can make a runnable snippet here on the site.

Comment: the code is in the link: https://codepen.io/Awesome_Billy_Bob/pen/MWZzMRG?editors=1000

Comment: "In the question itself" and "here on the site" imply not using a link. Links disappear over time--the point is to curate a resource for future visitors with the same problem as you, and write questions that are complete and self-contained. Please read [mcve]. Also relevant for improving your question: [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Thanks.

Comment: The stack editor is haveing some sort of problem, I am getting the message:
Error: { "message": "Script error.", "filename": "", "lineno": 0, "colno": 0 }

Comment: That's a problem with the code of some sort, not with Stack Snippets, so check to make sure you're copy-pasting it from your pen correctly, or look at the browser console to see if there's an error.

Comment: @AwesomeBillyBob Shame the question got closed so far. Hopefully it will be reopened again soon. I've pasted your JS code. This is what ggorlen suggested: I agree, even if the codepen gets deleted/changed, the syntax highlited text will live here (and it doesn't need to be a working running snippet). You can do 2 things: 1. call `video.hide()` in `setup()` (after instantiation); 2. replace `background("#ffffff");` (which makes an opaque white background) with the video: `image(video, 0, 0);`. Adjust to make it nicer (e.g. change y position, scale the shape of the circle head, etc.). Good luck!